# Action when tap on tableViewCell (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, iso

I want execute a code when user tap on tableViewCell, this is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titolo.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!
    let text1 = titolo[indexPath.row]
    let text2 = genere[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = text1
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = text2
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("test tap cell")
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songs().items
let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.applicationQueuePlayer

...
```

This function not work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("test tap cell")
}
```

"test tap cell" does not appear in the console.

Comment: Do cells get highlighted when tapped? Also make sure your viewcontroller instance is set as the tableview's delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set delegate and dataSource and implement  `didSelectRowAt` correctly

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titolo.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = text1
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = text2
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         print("test tap cell")
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now: I've added "UITableViewDelegate" and I replaced "didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath" with "didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath".
Thank you!